# Bash script to log the output of the script to a separate log file

Tags: shell-script

I have written a scipt(example.sh) to echo the date and system uptime on stdout. At the same time I want this script to log this output into a log file. 
Here's my code

```
echo `date`
echo `uptime`
```

And at last

```
cat /home/rpeb/example.sh 1> /home/rpeb/example.log
```

to redirect the output into a log file.

I don't want the last line to be logged. What changes should I make to this code?

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't want the last line to be logged` ? which last line?

Answer (score 3):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
{ date; uptime; } | tee "$HOME/example.log"
```

This would run `date` and `uptime` and pipe the output of both to `tee` which would write the data to the file `example.log` in the current user's home directory, *and* to the standard output of the script.
The `{ ...; }` is used to combine a set of commands into a "compound command" that can be redirected as a whole.

Without `{ ...; }`, you would need to do two redirections in the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
date   | tee    "$HOME/example.log"
uptime | tee -a "$HOME/example.log"
```

Note that the second invocation of `tee` needs the `-a` option to append to the logfile, or it would truncate it and you would lose the output of the `date` command.

---

You generally don't want to use `echo` just to output the result of a command substitution.  A command substitution (your back-ticked commands, or `$(...)`) may be useful for inserting the output of a command into a string, used by some other command, but to just *output* the result of a command you don't need the command substitution or `echo` (you don't do `echo $(ls)` on the command line, and you don't do that in a script, for example).

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt. This is the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
echo `date`
echo `uptime`
```

but is better this way:

```
echo $(date)
echo $(uptime)
```

(read about why [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082))

---

And, in this particular case, you'll probably be fine just with:

```
date
uptime
```

---

this:

```
cat /home/rpeb/example.sh 1> /home/rpeb/example.log
```

**will not** execute your script.

`cat /home/rpeb/example.sh` is just printing the content of `/home/rpeb/example.sh`

and then, you are redirecting `stdout` from that command, to the file `/home/rpeb/example.log`. So, what your are really doing here, is making a copy of `/home/rpeb/example.sh` into `/home/rpeb/example.log`.
Seems that this is not what you want.

But in case you do, this is more succinct:

```
cat /home/rpeb/example.sh > /home/rpeb/example.log
```

when you just use `>`, the `1` before it is implied.

---

If you want to run the script `/home/rpeb/example.sh`, and then redirect its output to the file `/home/rpeb/example.log`, first, give execute permissions to `/home/rpeb/example.sh`, this way:

```
chmod u+x /home/rpeb/example.sh
```

then, you run the script, simply writing its path, then redirecting its output, like this:

```
/home/rpeb/example.sh > /home/rpeb/example.log
```

and, btw, if both files (your script, and your log to be) are in the same `dir`, and you are inside that `dir`, you con simply run:

```
./example.sh > example.log
```

And if you want the output from `example.sh` printed on your terminal, and logged into `example.log`, you can do that this way:

```
./example.sh | tee example.log
```